# The type or namespace name 'IHolidayProvider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

This is the code I have below. It's for unit testing. I also have an error for Returns(holidays). It says "(local variable) List holidays
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DateProject.Holiday>' to '?'"

The error showed when I added "using System.Collections.Generic;"

```
[Fact]
public void WhatHolidaysAreOnThisDay_FindHolidays_ReturnsHolidays() {

    // Arrange

    var holidayProvider = new Mock<IHolidayProvider>();
    List<Holiday> holidays = new List<Holiday>() {
        new Holiday() {TheDate=new Date(2020, 6, 2), Name="Beach Day"},
        new Holiday() {TheDate= new Date(2020, 6, 2), Name = "Pizza Day"}
    };
    holidayProvider.Setup(m=> m.GetHolidays(2020)).Returns(holidays);  

    Date date = new Date(2020, 6, 2, holidayProvider.Object);

    // Act

    List<string> findHolidays = date.WhatHolidaysAreOnThisDay();

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal("Beach Day", findHolidays[0]);
    Assert.Equal("Pizza Day", findHolidays[1]);
}
```

Comment: Is the `IHolidayProvider` type declared as `internal` in another assembly (or not declared as `public`)? If so, it won't be visible to the unit test assembly, and you should probably make it public. Note: If you don't explicitly declare an interface to be `public`, it will be `internal`.

Comment: This is what I have for IHolidayProvider in another file:                                                                     namespace DateProject {

    public class HolidayProvider {
        public  List<Holiday> GetHolidays(int year) {
            List<Holiday> list1 = new List<Holiday>() ;